# Creating a symbolic link between extentionless files

Tags: windows-7, windows, symbolic-link, windows-10-preview

I’m running Windows 7 on one partition, and Windows 10 on another partition. I’m trying to use my Windows 7 hosts file in place of the Windows 10 one, since it has information in it used by XAMPP. That way I don’t have to keep two files up to date.

However, when I run this command:

```
mklink /D hosts D:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

It’s made as a directory link instead of a file link. Is there a way to make Windows know that I’m linking files, and not folders?

Comment: @JakeGould, Hasn't changed since XP, doubt it's going to change this run either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot hardlink a file across two file systems (e.g. C: and D:). You will need to use some kind of file synchronization program to keep the two files in sync, and you need to set it up on both OS.

You can create a directory junction, but it will link the entire folder.